# Sharing an ORM between languages

Tags: python, .net, database, orm

I am making a database with data in it.  That database has two customers: 1) a .NET webserver that makes the data visible to users somehow someway. 2) a python dataminer that creates the data and populates the tables.

I have several options. I can use the .NET Entity Framework to create the database, then reverse engineer it on the python side.  I can vice versa that.  I can just write raw SQL statements in one or the other systems, or both.  What are possible pitfalls of doing this one way or the other?  I'm worried, for example, that if I use the python ORM to create the tables, then I'm going to have a hard time in the .NET space...

Comment: For `python` you might want to look into [`SQLAlchemy automap`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) and [`django inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/). Though both come with some limitations.

Comment: I'm aware that these are things, but in my experience, such functions are designed to be "run once, then use Code First in the future".  I can only "Code First" in one language or the other, so I will be SQLAlchemy automapping every day.  Who makes this easier, automap or inspectdb?

Comment: I do not know, though SQLAlchemy automap seems more ephemeral since it is reflected on demand. Another approach to this problem is for the dataminer to read/write to the db through an API offered by the webserver. The dataminer would then be separated from its concern regarding the underlying database layer. Just my two-cents.

Answer (score 1):

I love questions like that.
Here is what you have to consider, your web site has to be fast, and the bottleneck of most web sites is a database. The answer to your question would be - make it easy for .NET to work with SQL. That will require little more work with python, like specifying names of the table, maybe row names. I think Django and SQLAlchemy are both good for that.

Another solution could be to have a bridge between database with gathered data and database to display data. On a background you can have a task/job to migrate collected data to your main database. That is also an option and will make your job easier, at least all database-specific and strange code will go to the third component.

I've been working with .NET for quite a long time before I switched to python, and what you should know is that whatever strategy you chose it will be possible to work with data in both languages and ORMs. Do the hardest part of the job in the language your know better. If you are a Python developer - pick python to mess with the right names of tables and rows.